# What are these strange knobs and how can I remove them?

Tags: bathroom-fixtures, knobs

We moved into a new house and the bathroom has two of these strange knobs in. They are barely big enough to hold a towel and are not close enough to be attachments for a towel rack.

[image]

When I twist them they turn without unscrewing and it seems like there is a rivet going through them to attach them to the wall.

Has anyone seen these before or know how they are attached? Do I just need to saw them off? I’d prefer to remove them sensibly.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Many stores sell these knobs. Most probably it is fastened with cavity toggle bolt. If you pull it, maintain pressure and turn anti-clockwise, it may unscrew.